# Autofac intentional circular dependency

Tags: autofac

With Autofac, what is the proper way to register types or declare dependencies for this type of circular graph?

```
public interface IComponent
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class AComponent: IComponent
{
    ...
}

public class BComponent: IComponent
{
    ...
}

public class CompositeComponent: IComponent
{
    public CompositeComponent(IEnumerable<IComponent> components)
    {
        this.components = components;
    }

    public void DoSomething() 
    {
        foreach(var component in components)
            component.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

The end goal would be that CompositeComponent be the default registration of IComponent and simply pass down calls to all other implementations.

Comment: Where is the circularity? `CompositeComponent` depends on `AComponent` and `BComponent`, but `AComponent` and `BComponent` do not depend on `CompositeComponent`. Could you explain where this circularity is?

Comment: I gather the "circle" is the fact the `CompositeComponent` is an `IComponent` but it also needs to _take in_ all the `IComponent` instances _except itself_. I'll provide an answer, but the short version is that this is kind of a design problem.

Comment: @Steven, I apologize for the delayed response but Travis is correct.  The absence of constraining facets on AComponent and BComponent and the open dependency of CompositeComponent causes a circular dependency by CompositeComponent upon itself.  We can use metadata or keyed services in the registration of CompositeComponent to constrain the injection's properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am gathering that the intent of the question is that you have some implementations of `IComponent` and you have some sort of `CompositeComponent` that also implements `IComponent`. `CompositeComponent` needs all of the registered `IComponent` instances *except itself* otherwise it creates a circular dependency.

This whole thing overlaps pretty heavily with one of our FAQs: ["How do I pick a service implementation by context?"](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html)

You have some options. In order of my personal recommendation:

**Option 1: Redesign the Interfaces**

There are actually two concepts going on here - the notion of an *individual handler* and the notion of a thing that *aggregates a set of individual handlers*.

Using less generic terms, you might have an `IMessageHandler` interface and then something that passes a message through the *set of all `IMessageHandler` implementations*, but that thing that aggregates the handlers and deals with errors and ensuring the message is handled only by the right handler and all that... that isn't, *itself*, also a message handler. It's a message *processor*. So you'd actually have two different interfaces, even if the methods on the interface look the same - `IMessageHandler` and `IMessageProcessor`.

Back in your generic component terms, that'd mean you have `IComponent` like you do now, but you'd also add an `IComponentManager` interface. `CompositeComponent` would change to implement that.

```
public interface IComponentManager
{
    void DoSomething();
}


public class ComponentManager : IComponentManager
{
    public ComponentManager(IEnumerable<IComponent> components)
    {
        this.components = components;
    }

    public void DoSomething() 
    {
        foreach(var component in components)
            component.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

**Option 2: Use Keyed Services**

If you won't (or can't) redesign, you can "flag" which registrations should contribute to the composite by using service keys. When you register the composite, don't use a key... but do specify that the parameter you want for the constructor should resolve from the keyed contributors.

```
builder.RegisterType<AComponent>()
       .Keyed<IComponent>("contributor");
builder.RegisterType<BComponent>()
       .Keyed<IComponent>("contributor");
builder.RegisterType<CompositeComponent>()
       .As<IComponent>()
       .WithParameter(
         new ResolvedParameter(
           (pi, ctx) => pi.Name == "components",
           (pi, ctx) => ctx.ResolveKeyed<IEnumerable<IComponent>>("contributor")));
```

When you resolve `IComponent` without providing a key, you'll get the `CompositeComponent` since it's the only one that was registered that way.

**Option 3: Use Lambdas**

If you know up front the set of components that should go into the composite, you could just build that up in a lambda and not over-DI the whole thing.

```
builder.Register(ctx =>
  {
    var components = new IComponent[]
    {
      new AComponent(),
      new BComponent()
    };
    return new CompositeComponent(components);
  }).As<IComponent>();
```

It's more manual, but it's also very clear. You could resolve individual constructor parameters for `AComponent` and `BComponent` using the `ctx` lambda parameter if needed.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer kind sir.  Also, thank you for the link. 
 I known I've read that before but approaching this with new eyes and your added direction, I understand much better what I was missing.  In my particular use case, using keyed services appears to be the correct solution.